# just curious to know the difference between spring mvc vs django

Tags: java, python, django, model-view-controller, spring-mvc

I would like to ask the masters out there as what are the main differences between java spring mvc and django? and also..which one is preferred most?

Comment: Well I'd think the biggest difference between the two is that they're frameworks for two completely different languages? Django has a much better name though ;)

Comment: Good article about this subject on [quora.com](https://www.quora.com/Shall-I-choose-Spring-Boot-or-Django). Results : it depends! No programming language are perfect for all situations. Like in life, if someone had found one answer for all questions, we would know! (kidding)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the perspective of developing Web applications, there's only the big difference in the approach towards the architecture of your applications.

Django tends to impose a lot of constraints and depends heavily on a fixed set of solutions that are provided internally. What you get from that are conventions and a streamlined approach to how you're developing your applications. Most of the framework solutions work for everybody and when they don't, you have plenty of opportunities to either extend or reuse certain components differently. This works out so well that, really, once you've seen one good Django project you've seen all of them.

Spring, on the other hand, tends to impose as little constraints as possible. Aside from satisfying Java EE platform requirements, you're at the liberty to pretty much wire your application in any way you'd see fit. The components that you write to provide actual behavior are intended to be as loosely tied to the framework itself and you'd just end up using certain components provided by Spring to manage how they're discovered, wired, managed and consumed. The problem is that you're at the liberty to customize even the most minute aspect of the application, which means that you'd be making a lot of decisions and every Spring Web application will be uniquely designed.

Comment: The above does not describe Django well at all!  Both are powerful MVC frameworks, it comes down to your language of choice. Python is easier to lear,  read, and write and has less boiler plate.

Comment: @radtek, the fact that they're written in languages with different paradigms is significant, but it is an obvious point and hardly relevant since the OP didn't ask to compare Java and Python. I've chosen to objectively compare the two from the architectural standpoint and I would appreciate if you could elaborate where exactly have I provided a misguided representation of Django to that extent.

Comment: Django tends to impose a lot of constraints and depends heavily on a fixed set of solutions that are provided internally <- it doesn't impose that you use it, but it is there if you need it. You can write your own solution anyway you like in python. The languages the frameworks are written in also has great impact. Also, not every django project it the same. I think your review is very subjective, and sounds like you use Spring and haven't explored Django apart from what you read.

Comment: Yes, I did say that because Django is a monolithic framework composed of interrelated components that have a tight cohesion and impose numerous conventions for discovery and interaction with your application sources, which is relevant to Spring, Spring MVC. In what followed your quote, I said that as a good thing which has been proven to work and outlined that you have plenty of opportunities to interject and modify existing behavior.

Comment: SO isn't a space to discuss personal affairs, so I'll just point out that this was not about describing Django in detail, one can refer to the official documentation for that. What is lacking, however, is a comparison between Spring MVC, which is a non-constructive question, the answers are meant to be subjective and mine has touched only upon the major architectural differences as being of the most significant importance from my subjective world view.

Comment: Anything you can do in python you can integrate into django, its not tightly coupled / restrictive at all ...  Django tends to impose a lot of constraints and depends heavily on a fixed set of solutions that are provided internally.  <- this line is completely false.

Comment: I like to speak directly my observations rather than speak in abstract confusing terms. Django uses file specific naming conventions such as app1/models.py or app1/views.py when you build your web app. Django's configuration file is in python syntax also. SpringMVC does not have that much file naming conventions and SpringMVC uses heavily a lot of XML magic to stitch together various parts. Try to research how each framework supports WebSocket and you will see that Java's more granular construct and process has an advantage.

Comment: This is a very good answer.

Answer (score 11):

Spring has its own web MVC framework, but it's much more:

1. A dependency injection/inversion of control factory
2. Aspect oriented programming.
3. Modules for persistence, remoting, and other features.

Django is a Python web MVC framework for creating browser UI CRUD applications.

I would say that Grails, a Ruby on Rails-like web CRUD framework for Java that's based on Spring, Hibernate, and Groovy, would be a better analogy for Django.  Both use "convention over coding" to speed development along.

Comment: Django is more productive, see here: http://www.quora.com/Python-and-Django-over-Java-Spring-who-made-the-switch-to-Python-Productivity-gains

Comment: I found this article more detailed : [quora](https://www.quora.com/Shall-I-choose-Spring-Boot-or-Django)

Comment: Spring MVC applications are better customized for complex use-cases. We are using since 2009 in SaaS application for EdTech solution https://www.eisdigital.com and able to accommodate all customer changes easily without breaking existing functionality . The annotation makes is quite better then mapping URL in Django manually.  Also great tools for development like Eclipse and NetBeans whereas I'm happy with IDE with intelligence for Python.

Comment: Nice comment, but you're nine years late.  Eclipse and NetBeans?  Poor choices compared to IntelliJ from JetBrains.  You should look into PyCharm for Python, too.