# Spring MVC and Django

Tags: django, spring-mvc

I am an Engineer turned Web Developer with some experience in Django. Recently I got a work related to Spring MVC. My knowledge of Java is very limited. I know that Java is used at enterprise level applications more as compared to Python. What I would like to know is in web development when would it be preferable to use Spring MVC and when to use Django? What would be the basis for deciding the framework? If I should decide over either of these, apart from the fact that familiarity in either of these frameworks matters the most, what would be the parameters to decide?

Comment: possibly duplicate [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547226/just-curious-to-know-the-difference-between-spring-mvc-vs-django]

Answer (score 2):

Spring MVC is web framework used ofr building web applications in java. Yet, Spring is heavy weight framework it includes lot of things such as **Spring security, Spring Rest, Spring Batch, Spring MQ and so on**.  Spring focuses on the *plumbing* of enterprise applications so that teams can focus on application-level business logic, without unnecessary ties to specific deployment environments. So it is useful for *building enterprise applications*. You could see that **Netflix, Yatra.com** those websites are build on **Spring** and relevant technologies.

It does not mean you can't do similar one with Django web-framework. It is *lightweight framework* with lots of features like **Django admin, Django orm, Templates, Django rest framework and so on** which is easy to setup like piece of cake which is useful to boost your development speed. There are many thirdparty packages available to use with Django framework. There are several top websites build on Django framework such as Intagram, Pinterest, BitBucket.

So cheerup! feel free to choose any of them. Both can be used to integrate scalable web applications